# Link using twig tag

Tags: symfony, twig

I have an entity `Documentation` which has an attribute

```
     /**
      * @var string
      *
      * @ORM\Column(name="url", type="string", length=255)
      */
     private $url;
```

I did not generate the crud for this entity because I create a Documentation via another entity.

But now, I am creating an administration panel and I will like to list my documentation and put a `<a>` tag to redirect to the `$url`.

With twig :

```
     {% for doc in docs %}
        <a href="{{ doc.url }}">{{ doc.name }}</a>
     {% endfor %}
```

But now, to access to my panel the path is `127.0.0.1:8000/liste/`. I have my list it is ok. But for example if doc's url is `www.youtube.com`, if I click on the link it redirects me to `127.0.0.1:8000/liste/www.youtube.com` ... And I do not understand... I am not using `path` ?

Comment: add `http://` to link if not already present

Comment: It's working thanks @ArtOsi

Comment: @ArtOsi could you add this as an answer so this question won't appear unanswered?

Comment: @Veve ok, I will do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add `http://` to link if not already present.

You could also create custom twig extension http://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html and add `http://` only for links where needed (where not already present) .